# NUll reference exception at webrequest.create(URL)

Tags: web-services

I m getting a null reference exception in the line `webrequest.create(v_strURL)`

```
Dim objHttpWebRequest As HttpWebRequest
        Dim objHttpWebResponse As HttpWebResponse
        Dim objRequestStream As Stream = Nothing
        Dim objResponseStream As Stream = Nothing

        Dim objXMLReader As XmlTextReader

        objHttpWebRequest = CType((WebRequest.Create(v_strURL)), HttpWebRequest) ''This line throws exception.
```

The `Url` is correct and does give a proper response .

Comment: Yeah, but Microsoft made it obsolete in .NET 4.5

See [other stack overflow thread...][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18203835/httpwebrequest-in-c-sharp-do-not-work-with-net-4-5