# HttpWebRequest in c# do not work with .net 4.5

Tags: c#, .net, httpwebrequest

i'm working on an c# project that send a xml to a server and receives a xml as response.
With .Net Framework 4.0 installed that works fine.
With .Net Framework 4.5 installed it throws this Exception:

```
System.NullReferenceException: Der Objektverweis wurde nicht auf eine Objektinstanz festgelegt.  
bei System.DomainNameHelper.IdnEquivalent(String hostname)  
bei System.Uri.get_IdnHost()  
bei System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetSafeHostAndPort(Uri sourceUri, Boolean addDefaultPort, Boolean forcePunycode)  
bei System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GenerateProxyRequestLine(Int32 headersSize)  
bei System.Net.HttpWebRequest.SerializeHeaders()  
bei System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndSubmitRequest()  
bei System.Net.HttpWebRequest.CheckDeferredCallDone(ConnectStream stream)  
bei System.Net.HttpWebRequest.BeginGetResponse(AsyncCallback callback, Object state)  
bei Fahrzeugverwaltungsserver.OutsideWorld.MAN_Integrationsserver.RawCommunication.ISServer.doPostAndGet()`
```

I use the method `BeginGetResponse` and all parameters there are not null.
Does anybody know what's wrong?
Why does it work with 4.0 but not with 4.5?
Did i forget something to set up?

**Edit 1**

```
private void doPostAndGet()
    {
        try
        {
            //caching  
            inform(SystemIcons.Information, Translations.ISServer_postAndGet_0);  
            Trace.TraceInformation("OUT:\n" + Beautify(InputXML));  

            string c = cache.Get(InputXML.OuterXml);
            if (c != null)
            {
                XmlDocument docl = new XmlDocument();
                docl.LoadXml(c);
                inform(SystemIcons.Information, Translations.ISServer_postAndGet_1);
                printInDocument(docl, "Aus Cache.");
                this.doc = docl;
            }

            //Read access information:
            UriBuilder urib = new UriBuilder("http", MANHaendlerdaten.IS_host, 9005, MANHaendlerdaten.IS_path);

            urib.UserName = MANHaendlerdaten.IS_user;
            urib.Password = MANHaendlerdaten.IS_password;

            String proxyUser = MANHaendlerdaten.IS_proxy_user;
            String proxyPassword = MANHaendlerdaten.IS_proxy_password;

            // create credentials for request's header:
            var proxy =
            Convert.ToBase64String(
            Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(proxyUser + ":" + proxyPassword));

            var user =
            Convert.ToBase64String(
            Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(urib.UserName + ":" + urib.Password));

            //set proxy when needed:
            try
            {
                WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy = new WebProxy(MANHaendlerdaten.IS_proxy_ip, MANHaendlerdaten.IS_proxy_port);
                if (WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy == null)
                    Trace.WriteLine(String.Format("WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy ist null. {0}, {1}", MANHaendlerdaten.IS_proxy_ip, MANHaendlerdaten.IS_proxy_port));
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Trace.TraceError("1\n" + e.ToString());
                Debug.WriteLine(Translations.ISServer_postAndGet_3);
                WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy = null; //speed up further request by avoiding proxy-auto-detect
                //pass when no proxy specified
            }

            // System.Net.ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = false //this is a nasty one if not set to false            

            client = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(urib.Uri);

            //Encodings:
            client.Headers.Add("Accept-Encoding", "deflate");

            client.ContentType = "text/xml; charset=UTF-8";

            client.Accept = "text/xml; charset=UTF-8";

            client.Headers.Add("SOAPAction", "\"\"");

            //Authentification:        
            client.Headers.Add("Proxy-Authorization", "Basic " + proxy);

            client.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic " + user);


            //Connection and Protocol:
            client.Host = urib.Host;

            client.UserAgent = Translations.FullServiceName;

            client.ProtocolVersion = HttpVersion.Version10;

            client.KeepAlive = true;

            client.Method = WebRequestMethods.Http.Post;

            client.Timeout = 60000;

            client.Proxy = new WebProxy(MANHaendlerdaten.IS_proxy_ip, MANHaendlerdaten.IS_proxy_port);

            if (client.Proxy == null)
                Trace.WriteLine(String.Format("client.Proxy ist null. {0}, {1}", MANHaendlerdaten.IS_proxy_ip, MANHaendlerdaten.IS_proxy_port));

            client.ReadWriteTimeout = 60000;


            //accept cookies within this ISServer-instance
            if (this.cookieCont == null)
            {
                this.cookieCont = new CookieContainer();
            }

            client.CookieContainer = cookieCont;


            inform(SystemIcons.Information, Translations.ISServer_postAndGet_7);

            //Post request:
            using (Stream to_request = client.GetRequestStream())
            {
                InputXML.Save(to_request);
                to_request.Flush();
            }


            RequestState myRequestState = new RequestState();
            myRequestState.request = client;


            webrequestresponse = false;
            IAsyncResult asyncResult = client.BeginGetResponse(new AsyncCallback(FinishWebRequest), myRequestState);
            while (webrequestresponse == false)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(100);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Trace.TraceError(e.ToString());
            throw e;
        }
}
```

**Edit 2**
In my Config File i use mostly the appsettings for individual settings. Like:
`<add key="DATABASE_CONNECTION" value="FIREBIRD"/>`

Comment: Can you show us your code?

Comment: Can you show us your .Config file?

Comment: Not sure how this worked in .net 4. Can you try using GetResponse() instead of BeginGetRespone?

Comment: You're having a `NullReferenceException` at `System.DomainNameHelper.IdnEquivalent(String hostname)`. See also [How to make HttpClient relay traffic show up in Fidder or Charles?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17824555/how-to-make-httpclient-relay-traffic-show-up-in-fidder-or-charles). Does this happen as soon as you update .NET 4 to .NET 4.5, or is it a different machine that has a proxy set up?

Comment: @CodeCaster It happens when i update the .Net Framework on the PC on which my programm runs. When version 4.0 is installed it works fine.

Answer (score 9):

To be honest as you are now targeting .NET 4.5 I would have a look into using `HttpClient` instead of HttpWebRequest.

[HttpClient](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/henrikn/archive/2012/02/16/httpclient-is-here.aspx)

Comment: Didnt do the downvote - its not really an answer to his question just a recommendation to use something else, such things should be a comment or a side note of a real answer.

Comment: I consider good advice on alternative options definitely qualify as an answer.  HttpClient is the new recommended way of consuming HTTP resources ... how is that NOT an answer?

Comment: To make it clear - just was my opinion about this matter. I wasnt the guy who downvoted, just believe that when the guy didnt provide a comment regarding the downvote in the first place he never will. It can not be considered an answer because it doesnt provide an answer just an alternative to do it - its like someone asks you "Hey why does my apple taste bad?" and you answer "Eat bannans." Its just no direct answer, but an alternative solution to his problem if your apple tastes bad, just eat something else, so if you face a problem with HttpWebRequest just use HttpClient.

Answer (score 6):

Strange there wasn't a serious answer posted already...

HttpWebRequest has been made obsolete in .NET 4.5 and later versions so it will not compile which is noted on the [msdn site](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc190216(v=vs.110).aspx)

This is why Jammer is saying to use [HttpClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient(v=vs.110).aspx) as a replacement since it seems to be the replacement microsoft has made for it.

Looks like it will be an effort to change your code but I'd say it's all for the best

Comment: The msdn article linked is specifically noting about the constructor, you can still create an instance via WebRequest.Create.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same strange problem in IdnEquivalent. The problem persisted when I had Fiddler web debugger launched during my debug session. After I shut it down the problem disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

As previously mentioned, HttpWebRequest is obsolete now. Have you tried HttpRequest? Found here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest(v=vs.110).aspx